# Incremental commit to optimise insert query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008r2-express

I have the following insert statement that i am running daily and updating approx 55,000 records.

```
    INSERT INTO dbo.ETL_INPUT (
    SCH_APPT_ID
    ,SCH_EVENT_ID
    ,MRN
    ,PERSON_ID
    ,NAME_FULL_FORMATTED
    ,Main_Bookshelf_Old
    ,Main_Bookshelf_New
    ,Old_Book_Shelf
    ,First_Book_Old
    ,First_Book_New
    ,Old_Book
    ,Second_Book_Old
    ,Second_Book_New
    ,Third_Book_Old
    ,Third_Book_New
    ,Final_Book_Old
    ,Final_Book_New
    ,Old_Clinic
    ,Old_Rsrc
    ,Rsrc_Old
    ,Rsrc_New
    ,Old_Appt_Type
    ,Appt_Type_Old
    ,Appt_Type_New
    ,Amb_Loc
    ,Amb_Loc_Old
    ,Amb_Loc_New
    ,SLOT_TYPE_ID
    ,BEG_DT_TM
    ,END_DT_TM
    ,DURATION
    ,SCH_COMMENT
    ,Appt_State
    ,XRay_Requested
    ,Referring_Physician
    ,PRIORITY
    ,TRANSPORT_MODE
    ,REASON_FOR_EXAM
    ,Reason_For_Exam_DCP
    ,Ambulance_Required
    ,Interpreter
    ,QH_LANGUAGE_SPOKEN
    ,Private_Patient
    ,RADIOLOGY_DIABETIC
    ,PREVIOUS_REACTION_TO_CONTRAST
    ,Urgency_Category
    ,New_Review
    ,Trial_Pt_information
    ,CONSULTING_PHYSICIAN
    ,QH_REFERRAL_DATE_RECEIVED
    ,Date_Planned_for_Operating_Theatre
    ,QH_REFERRAL_DATE_CATEGORISED
    ,QH_REFERRAL_DATE
    ,RADIOLOGY_ASTHMATIC
    ,SCHEDULING_ORDER_TYPE
    ,RADIOLOGY_SCHEDULING_ORDERING_PHYSICIAN
    ,RADIOLOGY_INPATIENT_OUTPATIENT
    ,CONFIDENTIALITY_LEVEL
    ,RADIOLOGY_CONTRAST_3CS
    ,RADIOLOGY_MRI_IS_THIS_PATIENT_IN_THE_0715_TIME_SLOT
    ,Multidisiplinary_Care_Plan_Clinic
    ,Admittable_Procedure
    ,QH_ISIS_REQUEST_NUMBER
    ,QH_APPOINTMENT_REFERRAL_SOURCE
    ,QH_Not_Ready_For_Care_Start_Date
    ,QH_Not_Ready_For_Care_End_Date
    ,QH_REFERRAL_CATEGORY_CODE
    ,QH_LOCATION_REGION_CODE
    ,QH_LOCATION_ZONE_CODE
    ,QH_LOCATION_STATE_CODES
    ,QH_FACILITY_CODES
    ,QH_INTENDED_FINANCIAL_PAYMENT_CLASS
    ,QH_SERVICE_DELIVERY_MODE
    ,QH_DELIVERY_SETTING
    ,RADIOLOGY_REQUIRED_BY_DATE
    ,RADIOLOGY_BMD_SCAN_DATE_PRIOR_SCAN
    ,OP_Sub_Specialty_Code
    ,OP_Category_Code
    ,OP_Session_Type
    ,OP_Service_Delivery_Code
    ,OP_Clinic_Type
    ,OP_Delivery_Setting
    ,OP_Care_Type
    ,OP_Service_Type
    ,OP_Referral_Source
    ,OP_Provisional_Diagnosis
    ,OP_Ready_For_Care
    ,OP_Last_Clinical_Update_Date
    ,OP_Referral_Duration
    ,OP_Corporate_Clinic_Code
    ,QH_APPOINTMENT_STANDBY_CODE
    ,RADIOLOGY_AFTER_HOURS_ARRIVAL_VARIATION_RECEPTION_DESK
    ,Clinical_Area
    )
SELECT SCH_APPT_ID
    ,SCH_EVENT_ID
    ,MRN
    ,PERSON_ID
    ,NAME_FULL_FORMATTED
    ,Main_Bookshelf_Old
    ,Main_Bookshelf_New
    ,Old_Book_Shelf
    ,First_Book_Old
    ,First_Book_New
    ,Old_Book
    ,Second_Book_Old
    ,Second_Book_New
    ,Third_Book_Old
    ,Third_Book_New
    ,Final_Book_Old
    ,Final_Book_New
    ,Old_Clinic
    ,Old_Rsrc
    ,Rsrc_Old
    ,Rsrc_New
    ,Old_Appt_Type
    ,Appt_Type_Old
    ,Appt_Type_New
    ,Old_Amb_Loc
    ,Amb_Loc_Old
    ,Amb_Loc_New
    ,SLOT_TYPE_ID
    ,BEG_DT_TM
    ,END_DT_TM
    ,DURATION
    ,SCH_COMMENT
    ,Appt_State
    ,XRay_Requested
    ,Referring_Physician
    ,PRIORITY
    ,TRANSPORT_MODE
    ,REASON_FOR_EXAM
    ,Reason_For_Exam_DCP
    ,Ambulance_Required
    ,Interpreter
    ,QH_LANGUAGE_SPOKEN
    ,Private_Patient
    ,RADIOLOGY_DIABETIC
    ,PREVIOUS_REACTION_TO_CONTRAST
    ,Urgency_Category
    ,New_Review
    ,Trial_Pt_information
    ,CONSULTING_PHYSICIAN
    ,QH_REFERRAL_DATE_RECEIVED
    ,Date_Planned_for_Operating_Theatre
    ,QH_REFERRAL_DATE_CATEGORISED
    ,QH_REFERRAL_DATE
    ,RADIOLOGY_ASTHMATIC
    ,SCHEDULING_ORDER_TYPE
    ,RADIOLOGY_SCHEDULING_ORDERING_PHYSICIAN
    ,RADIOLOGY_INPATIENT_OUTPATIENT
    ,CONFIDENTIALITY_LEVEL
    ,RADIOLOGY_CONTRAST_3CS
    ,RADIOLOGY_MRI_IS_THIS_PATIENT_IN_THE_0715_TIME_SLOT
    ,Multidisiplinary_Care_Plan_Clinic
    ,Admittable_Procedure
    ,QH_ISIS_REQUEST_NUMBER
    ,QH_APPOINTMENT_REFERRAL_SOURCE
    ,QH_Not_Ready_For_Care_Start_Date
    ,QH_Not_Ready_For_Care_End_Date
    ,QH_REFERRAL_CATEGORY_CODE
    ,QH_LOCATION_REGION_CODE
    ,QH_LOCATION_ZONE_CODE
    ,QH_LOCATION_STATE_CODES
    ,QH_FACILITY_CODES
    ,QH_INTENDED_FINANCIAL_PAYMENT_CLASS
    ,QH_SERVICE_DELIVERY_MODE
    ,QH_DELIVERY_SETTING
    ,RADIOLOGY_REQUIRED_BY_DATE
    ,RADIOLOGY_BMD_SCAN_DATE_PRIOR_SCAN
    ,OP_Sub_Specialty_Code
    ,OP_Category_Code
    ,OP_Session_Type
    ,OP_Service_Delivery_Code
    ,OP_Clinic_Type
    ,OP_Delivery_Setting
    ,OP_Care_Type
    ,OP_Service_Type
    ,OP_Referral_Source
    ,OP_Provisional_Diagnosis
    ,OP_Ready_For_Care
    ,OP_Last_Clinical_Update_Date
    ,OP_Referral_Duration
    ,OP_Corporate_Clinic_Code
    ,QH_APPOINTMENT_STANDBY_CODE
    ,RADIOLOGY_AFTER_HOURS_ARRIVAL_VARIATION_RECEPTION_DESK
    ,Clinical_Area
FROM dbo.vw_ETL_INPUT

EXCEPT

SELECT SCH_APPT_ID
    ,SCH_EVENT_ID
    ,MRN
    ,PERSON_ID
    ,NAME_FULL_FORMATTED
    ,Main_Bookshelf_Old
    ,Main_Bookshelf_New
    ,Old_Book_Shelf
    ,First_Book_Old
    ,First_Book_New
    ,Old_Book
    ,Second_Book_Old
    ,Second_Book_New
    ,Third_Book_Old
    ,Third_Book_New
    ,Final_Book_Old
    ,Final_Book_New
    ,Old_Clinic
    ,Old_Rsrc
    ,Rsrc_Old
    ,Rsrc_New
    ,Old_Appt_Type
    ,Appt_Type_Old
    ,Appt_Type_New
    ,Amb_Loc
    ,Amb_Loc_Old
    ,Amb_Loc_New
    ,SLOT_TYPE_ID
    ,BEG_DT_TM
    ,END_DT_TM
    ,DURATION
    ,SCH_COMMENT
    ,Appt_State
    ,XRay_Requested
    ,Referring_Physician
    ,PRIORITY
    ,TRANSPORT_MODE
    ,REASON_FOR_EXAM
    ,Reason_For_Exam_DCP
    ,Ambulance_Required
    ,Interpreter
    ,QH_LANGUAGE_SPOKEN
    ,Private_Patient
    ,RADIOLOGY_DIABETIC
    ,PREVIOUS_REACTION_TO_CONTRAST
    ,Urgency_Category
    ,New_Review
    ,Trial_Pt_information
    ,CONSULTING_PHYSICIAN
    ,QH_REFERRAL_DATE_RECEIVED
    ,Date_Planned_for_Operating_Theatre
    ,QH_REFERRAL_DATE_CATEGORISED
    ,QH_REFERRAL_DATE
    ,RADIOLOGY_ASTHMATIC
    ,SCHEDULING_ORDER_TYPE
    ,RADIOLOGY_SCHEDULING_ORDERING_PHYSICIAN
    ,RADIOLOGY_INPATIENT_OUTPATIENT
    ,CONFIDENTIALITY_LEVEL
    ,RADIOLOGY_CONTRAST_3CS
    ,RADIOLOGY_MRI_IS_THIS_PATIENT_IN_THE_0715_TIME_SLOT
    ,Multidisiplinary_Care_Plan_Clinic
    ,Admittable_Procedure
    ,QH_ISIS_REQUEST_NUMBER
    ,QH_APPOINTMENT_REFERRAL_SOURCE
    ,QH_Not_Ready_For_Care_Start_Date
    ,QH_Not_Ready_For_Care_End_Date
    ,QH_REFERRAL_CATEGORY_CODE
    ,QH_LOCATION_REGION_CODE
    ,QH_LOCATION_ZONE_CODE
    ,QH_LOCATION_STATE_CODES
    ,QH_FACILITY_CODES
    ,QH_INTENDED_FINANCIAL_PAYMENT_CLASS
    ,QH_SERVICE_DELIVERY_MODE
    ,QH_DELIVERY_SETTING
    ,RADIOLOGY_REQUIRED_BY_DATE
    ,RADIOLOGY_BMD_SCAN_DATE_PRIOR_SCAN
    ,OP_Sub_Specialty_Code
    ,OP_Category_Code
    ,OP_Session_Type
    ,OP_Service_Delivery_Code
    ,OP_Clinic_Type
    ,OP_Delivery_Setting
    ,OP_Care_Type
    ,OP_Service_Type
    ,OP_Referral_Source
    ,OP_Provisional_Diagnosis
    ,OP_Ready_For_Care
    ,OP_Last_Clinical_Update_Date
    ,OP_Referral_Duration
    ,OP_Corporate_Clinic_Code
    ,QH_APPOINTMENT_STANDBY_CODE
    ,RADIOLOGY_AFTER_HOURS_ARRIVAL_VARIATION_RECEPTION_DESK
    ,Clinical_Area
FROM dbo.ETL_INPUT`
```

I am wondering if there is a way to optimize this by incrementally commiting records rather than trying to do all at once?

Comment: Can you explain why you want an incremental commit? 55k rows is pretty small.

Comment: First, check if the problem is with the select or the insert. see how much time will it take to execute just the select part, and how much time will it take for the insert as well. check the execution plan to find the bottlenecks .

Comment: because this has to be run in business hours and currently taking close to 2.5 hours. i figured if i can incrementally insert i would speed my business processes up.